# cover string parts into quotes Node.js

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to get string like

```
'--variable1-name':'variable1Value',
'--variable2-name':'variable2Value',
```

from

```
--variable1-name:variable1Value,
--variable2-name:variable2Value,
```

but don't know how to split string correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what it is you want, since the string you claimed you want to create doesn't look like a string. It looks more like two key-value pairs.

But assuming that you want to create a JavaScript object from a string formatted as in your "from" example, you could achieve that like this:

```js
const input = `--variable1-name:variable1Value,
--variable2-name:variable2Value,`;

const values = input
  .split(',')              // Split the input into an array, separated at each comma
  .map(s => s.trim())      // Remove trailing/leading whitespace
  .filter(Boolean)         // Remove empty elements from the array
  .reduce((acc, val) => {  // Run the resulting array through a reducer that transforms it into a key/value object
      const kv = val.split(':'); // Split the incoming line into its key and value parts
      acc[kv[0]] = kv[1];
      return acc;
    }, {});
    
console.log(values);
```

Let me know if this is not what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thank you exactly what i want to do!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a program that surrounds all groups of hyphens and word characters with quotes. It is not optimal, but it is concise.

```js
const str = `--variable1-name:variable1Value,
--variable2-name:variable2Value,`;

const res = str.replace(/[-\w]+/gi, group => `'${group}'`);

console.log(res);
```